# How do I use this unfold function?

Tags: haskell

I've been tasked with using this fold function which "takes a list and returns a tree".

```
data Tree a = Tip a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)


unfoldTree :: (a -> Either n (a, a)) -> a -> Tree n
unfoldTree g h  =
   case g h of
     Right (l, r) -> Node (unfoldTree g l) (unfoldTree g r)
     Left c       -> Tip c
```

`a = [Int] n = Int`

I believe I understand the concept here and I've tried to use the following helper method to test `unfoldTree`

```
createSimpleTree :: [a] -> Tree x
createSimpleTree xs = unfoldTree (\ys -> ys (firstHalf ys, secondHalf ys) ) xs
```

Although this does not work I believe it is due to the central line `ys -> ys (firstHalf ys, secondHalf ys)` as I am unsure how to use the `Either` (I am unaware of its official name sorry still learning!)

I've tried using lambda here but I'm not sure how to say if it's the LEFT do this if it's the RIGHT do that? Or I could be on the wrong track with that completely.

**Question:** How can I use `createSimpleTree [1,2,3,4]` as to produce a tree with the values?

Comment: Terminology nitpicking: your function is not a fold but an *un*fold (or an anamorphism, if you like fancy synonyms).

Comment: Yes my mistake, thank you I've updated the title.

Comment: To create an  `Either` you need to use the constructor `Right` like this `ys -> Right (firstHalf ys, secondHalf ys)`. But I'm not sure how it works for your  `(a, a)` type.

Comment: The official name of `Either` is `Either`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with these types that need addressing before you can even get started on writing the function. The first thing to note is that there's no way you could write a function with type `[a] -> Tree x` using this unfold: where are the values of type `x` coming from? You could try writing a function with type `[a] -> Tree a`, though, by moving values from the input list into the output tree.

The second problem is that it is impossible to represent an empty tree using this `Tree a` type: a `Tip` has at least one `a`, and a `Node` has at least two, since each of the two branches eventually leads to at least one `Tip`. Therefore, there is no possible way to handle the case of an empty input list: `createSimpleTree []` cannot complete successfully, regardless of your implementation of `createSimpleTree`.

If this were an assignment where the types and the implementation of `unfoldTree` were given to me up-front, I would double-check that I had read them right; if so, I'd give up on solving it at this point, and say "hey, these types you gave me are no good, what am I supposed to do now?". There are a few possible answers to this complaint: first, surely the signature of `createSimpleTree` will be fixed; second, either the Tree type will be amended (with a corresponding change to `unfoldTree`), or you will be given some sort of guarantee that `createSimpleTree` will never be called with an empty list. At that point you can get back to solving the problem.

If you're instead doing this on your own, I would say to fix the tree type and the signature of `unfoldTree` yourself. For example, I would start with

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

unfoldTree :: (a -> Maybe (n, a, a)) -> a -> Tree n
unfoldTree = undefined -- exercise for the reader

createSimpleTree :: [a] -> Tree a
createSimpleTree = unfoldTree f
  where f = undefined -- exercise for the reader
```

Answer (score 1):

[amalloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43194864/625403) makes perfect sense in explaining the type that is required from `createSimpleTree` and the problem that appears when passing an empty list.

If you have to solve `createSimpleTree` as is and don't care about creating a partial function (function that is not defined for all its inputs), here is how you could go about it:

```
createSimpleTree :: [a] -> Tree a
createSimpleTree xs = unfoldTree go xs
  where
    go :: [a] -> Either a ([a], [a])
    go []  = error "Empty list in createSimpleTree"
    go [x] = Left x
    go xs  =
      let n = length xs `div` 2
      in Right (take n xs, drop n xs)
```

Comment: If you're feeling more advanced you can use the `splitAt` function, and you can apply *eta* reduction to the definition of `createSimpleTree`